# how to know if a page is in mode design with code-behind

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want how to know if a page is in mode design with code-behind and/or xslt.

Does anyone knows how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Code-Behind you can use:

```
if( SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit ){
    // Page in Edit Mode.
}
```

In JavaScript, you can use:

```
if( document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value ){
    console.log( 'Page in Edit Mode' ); 
}
```

You can also use the EditModePanel Control if you just want to use markup. Here's a reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822364(v=office.15).aspx

*(These will only work on Publishing Pages)*

Comment: know how to do with XSLT (DFWP) ??